# How to set a default image if I can't find the user's image on imgur

Tags: php, image

I have default image and I want to use it when I can't find the user's image on imgur.com

For example this image :

[image]

using PHP

I have tried to use `md5_file` to compare

```
if (md5_file("https://imgur.com/$profile->image.png") === md5_file("https://imgur.com/asfasfasdfadsf.png"))`
```

but it gave an error

> md5_file(https://imgur.com/asf.png): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning, not an error, so you can just ignore it. `md5_file` will return `false` if it fails to calculate the hash. If you want to hide the warning, you can use [an error handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), the [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) function or the [stfu](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) operator.